# Navigating from BottomSheetFragment with Jetpack Navigation results with crash 'Action can not be found from current destination'

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation, android-bottomsheetdialog

This case might be a unique one because I do have some complicated navigation logic and I'm using extension functions(which I will share below shortly).

- Imagine having a Fragment(A) opening a BottomSheetFragment(B)
- And the BottomSheetFragment(B) has a button inside.
- Tapping on the button dismisses the BottomSheetFragment(B) and navigates to a new Fragment(C).

To handle this case, I'm using 2 extension functions:

```
fun <T> Fragment.setNavigationResult(key: String, result: T) {
    findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(key, result)
}
```

```
fun <T> Fragment.getNavigationResult(key: String) = findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<T>(key)
```

Implementation of `setNavigationResult` in BottomSheetFragment(B)

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener {
            dismiss()
            setNavigationResult(EVENT_CUSTOMER_SIGNUP_LOGIN, Event(true))
        }
```

Implementation of `getNavigationResult` in Fragment(A)

```
getNavigationResult<Event<Boolean>>(EVENT_CUSTOMER_SIGNUP_LOGIN)?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { event ->
            event.value?.let {
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.openCustomerLogin)
            }
        }
```

The application crashes with the below error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination openFragmentC cannot be found from the current destination Destination(FragmentB)
```

What I don't understand here is, the current destination is still `BottomSheetFragment(B)` even I called `dismiss` before.

When I add a delay before navigating to FragmentC, then the application does not crash.

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
                    delay(250)
                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.openCustomerLogin)
                }
```

I don't like the solution with `delay`, because it's not practical and can easily be forgotten in new implementations.

Sorry for the long post, I will appreciate it if you share your thoughts on this and assist me.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented like below

suppose below code for bottomsheet while click on button

```
 private fun closeBottomSheet() {
        findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("refresh", true)
        findNavController().navigateUp()
    }
```

and below code  for fragment A

```
val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME
                && navBackStackEntry.savedStateHandle.contains("refresh")
            ) {
                val result = navBackStackEntry.savedStateHandle.get<Boolean>("refresh")
                if (result!!) {
                    result.run {
                        // whatever you do , go from fragment A to Fragment C
                        navBackStackEntry.savedStateHandle.remove<Boolean>("refresh")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And also check you have define action in fragment A in navigation.xml

Comment: Hi gaurav gupta, I tried with findNavController().navigateUp() instead of dismiss. It still crashes without delay(250). 

Fragment A has the definition to navigate to Fragment C, but FragmentB does not.

Comment: if result is null, your app would crash in this instance, I would not use the code like that. You should instead do `result?.run { ... }`

Comment: In case of null or not null you write code like this
result?.let { result ->

           // whatever you do
            }